# check if data-table have specific value or not than delete this value

Tags: c#, ado.net

I upload excel file and export it to database but i should check if this file have an code or not if that code in this sheet import the file else stop the importing
that how I upload my excel file:

```
OpenFileDialog op1 = new OpenFileDialog();
op1.Title = "اختار ملف البنوك";
op1.Filter = "Excel Workbook| *.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm";
if (op1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel)
    return;
FileStream stream1 = new FileStream(op1.FileName, FileMode.Open);
IExcelDataReader excelreader1 = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream1);
DataSet result1 = excelreader1.AsDataSet();
```

Any help please

Comment: And what is that code? Do you mean a value in specific cell?

Comment: i mean a word or string

Comment: And this word is in which cell? If you don't know where you should look for it, you have to search entire dataset!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search the entire dataSet:

```
foreach (DataTable dt in result1)
  foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    foreach(DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
      if(!dr.IsNull(dc) && dr[dc].ToString() == "YOUR UNWANTED STRING")
        dr[dc] = ""; // or whatever
```